# Prove that a cubic function is either convex either concave along ]a,b[ ; a and b 2 of its roots

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials, convex-analysis

I am working on a real analysis problem that involves Rolle and the mean value theorems ...
I got to the final step that consists to prove that f, a cubic function , is either convex either concave along ]a,b[, where a and b are two consecutive roots.
I tried to prove it by calculating the expression of f''(x), but this seems unfruitful.
Could someone please provide a hint?

Comment: Yes..Sorry I didn't mention it

Comment: Hint: it's false, whether or not $a$ and $b$ are consecutive roots of $f$.

Comment: It switches from convex to concave only at roots of $f''$.  Not (in general) roots of $f$.

Answer (score 1):

This is not true. For $f(x)=x(x-2)(x-3)$, then $f''(x)= 6x-10$ vanishes at $x=5/3 \in (0,2)$.

Answer (score 0):

It's false. Consider, for example, $f_\alpha(x)=x^3-x+\alpha$. The second derivative is $6x$, which changes sign at $x=0$. So if $f$ has three distinct roots, which it certainly does for some values of $\alpha$, the only way for your conjecture to be true is if $x=0$ is a root of $f$. But the roots of $f$ depend on $\alpha$, so this can't possibly work.